# Why do I get a syntax error when I try to cross compile libperl for mips64?

Tags: c, perl, cross-compiling, configure, mips64

I'm trying to cross compile `net-snmp` for mips64, and in order to do that I need the `libperl` library. I tried to configure `libperl` for mips64 using the following command:

```sh
./Configure -Dcc=/home/toby/x-tools/mips64-n64-linux-gnu/bin/mips64-n64-linux-gnu-gcc -Dprefix=/home/toby/perl
```

But I got the following error:

```
Checking your choice of C compiler and flags for coherency...
I've tried to compile and run the following simple program:

#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("Ok\n"); return(0); }

I used the command:

/home/toby/x-tools/mips64-n64-linux-gnu/bin/mips64-n64-linux-gnu-gcc -o try -O -I/usr/local/include try.c
 ./try

and I got the following output:

./try: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
   The program compiled OK, but exited with status 2.
(The supplied flags or libraries might be incorrect.)

You have a problem.  Shall I abort Configure [y]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That looks like an error from your shell and not the compiler.  Particularly because gcc doesn't return "status 2" for a syntax error, but bash does.  The problem happens because you have **cross compiled** a program called `./try` for mips64.  How do you expect `./Configure` to execute it on your **host** pc?

Comment: @indiv You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to the "How can I fix this", question.  The answer depends a lot on libperl, but typically you run configure scripts with your host environment and then `make` with `CC` and other variables set to your cross compiler.  I'd certainly appreciate if @toocou self-answers the question with details after figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd turn:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() { printf("Ok\n"); return(0); }
```

Into:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main() { 
    printf("Ok\n"); 
    return(0); 
 }
```

And then run the compile command by hand to see which line really contains the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an error from your shell and not the compiler. Particularly because gcc doesn't return "status 2" for a syntax error, but bash does. The problem happens because you have cross compiled a program called ./try for mips64. How do you expect ./Configure to execute it on your host pc?  –  indiv